# BeautifulSoup only scraping half my table?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a webpage for a table using BeautifulSoup, but for some reason it is only scraping half the table. The half I'm getting is the part that doesn't contain the input fields. Here is the html data:

```html
<table class="commonTable1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="portAllocTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="commonTableHeaderLastCell" colspan="2"><span class="commonBold"> Portfolio Allocation (%) </span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="commonHeaderContentSeparator"><img src="/fees-web/common/images/spacer.gif" height="1" style="display: block"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>AdvisorGuided (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[0].feeCollectionRate" value="100" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[0].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="100" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>AdvisorGuided 2 (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[1].feeCollectionRate" value="0" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[1].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="0" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Client Directed (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[2].feeCollectionRate" value="0" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[2].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="0" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Holding MMKT (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[3].feeCollectionRate" value="0" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[3].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="0" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Total</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[4].feeCollectionRate" value="100" id="selText_1Total"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[4].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" value="100" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1TotalINPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my code:

```py
url = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', id="portAllocTable")
rows = table.findAll('td')

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll(["th","td"]):
        text = cell.text
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

for item in list_of_rows:
    print(' '.join(item))
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it only printing the left side of the table? Any recommendations about what to change would be much appreciated.

```
Results:

 Portfolio Allocation (%) 


AdvisorGuided (Capital Portfolio)
 100 100 




AdvisorGuided 2 (Capital Portfolio)
 0 100 




Client Directed (Capital Portfolio)
 0 100 




Holding MMKT (Capital Portfolio)
 0 100 




Total
 100 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to go further into the child and sibling nodes and pull out the attributes (those values aren't actual text/content.

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4


html = '''<table class="commonTable1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="portAllocTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="commonTableHeaderLastCell" colspan="2"><span class="commonBold"> Portfolio Allocation (%) </span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="commonHeaderContentSeparator"><img src="/fees-web/common/images/spacer.gif" height="1" style="display: block"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>AdvisorGuided (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[0].feeCollectionRate" value="100" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[0].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="100" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>AdvisorGuided 2 (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[1].feeCollectionRate" value="0" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[1].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="0" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Client Directed (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[2].feeCollectionRate" value="0" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[2].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="0" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Holding MMKT (Capital Portfolio)</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <!-- When collection method is invoice,  the portfolio to charge table should be diabled.
                    Else work as it was-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[3].feeCollectionRate" value="0" id="selText_1"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[3].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return disableMinus();" onblur="updateTotal(1);" value="0" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" showalertdialog="true" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1INPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Total</span>
            </td>
            <td class="commonTableBodyLastCell" align="right">
                <span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="portfolioChargeList[4].feeCollectionRate" value="100" id="selText_1Total"><input type="text" name="portfolioChargeList[4].feeCollectionRateINPUT" maxlength="3" value="100" maxvalue="100" decimals="0" blankifzero="true" id="selText_1TotalINPUT" style="text-align:right;width:50px" class="commonTextBoxAmount">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', id="portAllocTable")
rows = table.findAll('td')

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.find_all(["th","td"]):
        text = cell.text
        try:
            val = cell.find('input')['value']
            max_val = cell.find('input').next_sibling['maxvalue']
            list_of_cells.append(val)
            list_of_cells.append(max_val)
        except:
            pass
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

for item in list_of_rows:
    print(' '.join(item))
```

To make a table, you could do something like this. You'll have to do a bitt of clean up, but should get you going:

```
results = pd.DataFrame()
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_all(["th","td"]):
        text = cell.text
        try:
            val = cell.find('input')['value']
            max_val = cell.find('input').next_sibling['maxvalue']
        except:
            val = ''
            max_val = ''
            pass

        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[text, val, max_val]], columns=['text','value','maxvalue'])
        results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: That worked! The way its formatted needs some work, how would I go about improving the way it looks?

Comment: I'll take a look and help you out a little later (stepping away from the computer for a bit). Can you sort of give an example in your original post of how you'd like the table to look?

Comment: I guess I would just say that I'd like it to look good in an Excel spreadsheet because that's where it's ultimately going to end up. I'll add what this code spits out.

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind.

First: it should be `rows = table.findAll('tr')` as the `tr` HTML tag designates rows. Subsequently, it should `for row in table.findAll('td'):` as the `td` HTML tag is the cell tag. But you're not even using the `rows` variable, so the point is moot. If you want you could do something like this:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', id="portAllocTable")
rows = table.findAll("tr")

list_of_rows = []
for row in rows:
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll(['th', 'td']):
        text = cell.text
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

for item in list_of_rows:
    print(' '.join(item))
```

Second, this code wouldn't get the text in the input fields, so this is probably why you only see the text on the left side.

Finally, you could try a difference parser, such as `html5lib`.

Comment: Tried doing both things you suggested, swapped in tr and td in the spots you said and the output was blank. Tried switching to html5lib and it also had a blank return.

Comment: I updated the answer: it's probably because the code you are using doesn't take a look at the text inside the input fields. They don't seem to be populated to begin with (at leat not using HTML). Maybe they're populated using Javascript?

Comment: Your code does produce what I had previously after your update, I'm looking to pull out the ```value="0" maxvalue="100" ``` for each line. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Loons22 those are HTML attributes, which you access as such: `cell['maxvalue']`